# Unity3D's "3D" text is two dimensional. I will build my own

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity3D does not offer 3 dimensional text. They have a type of text that they call 3D text, but I don't know why because it has no depth, only height and width.

I need 3 dimensional text. Actually, I only need the numbers, 0 through 9. I have already made these in Blender.

I have no idea how to use my numbers in Unity. For context, I have a "score" that gets fed data from collision events, so it is not as simple as dragging and dropping these objects into my world.

Do I have to build a font or something? If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate that. Google doesn't give up too much in this search.

Comment: 3d are the models make the models

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**3D text** in Unitys context just means a text that **can be moved in 3D space** (not like GUI text that can only move on a 2 dimensional plane)

Unfortunately you cant just make your own "3D font" for unity or any other software that 
(blender does all the calculations himself to render text with depth)
so to archive what you want I'd:

- Create the 3D numbers (in blender)
- import them to your assets
- make a new script that fetches the data
- go through every character of the number

  - calculate the offset based on the position
  - instantiate the number from the assets
- Destroy the number assets if its no longer needed (to redraw the number)

Example for the loop (as requested) !**`Just the idea!`**! doesn't work by copy and paste:

```
int scoreData = whatever your number is;

LoopFunction(){

    string scoreText = scoreData.toString();
    string[] characters = new string[scoreText.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
     {
        Instantiate (Resources.Load (characters[i])) as GameObject;
        /*
        Make sure that "1.pfefab" to "9.prefab" files exists in  
        Resources folder and 'Resources' folder exists in 'Assets' folder.  

        Add the offset to a variable after instantiating  
        so the numbers wont overlap
        */
      }

}
```

Comment: So if my score goes up to say, 1000, I will have to do 1000 if statements? Where I just place the object where it goes kind of thing?

Comment: why would you (write?) a thousand if statements? just loop through the number and add some simple math to determin the position based on the number model's width

Comment: Can you show me a short example of this loop to give me the basic idea?

Comment: i cant do it in unity right now, but im going to add some pseudocode in a minute

Comment: Ok thanks I can't imagine looping through an ever changing number like idk i just dont get it right now.

Comment: Put them in a resource folder and name them after their number. Turn the score to a string and foreach character, load the asset.

Comment: Catwood can you write a short example? I don't understand foreach as well as I would like. Especially as it relates to assets.

Comment: `foreach (char number in score.ToString())
{
 
}` [Resource Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)

Comment: if (col.gameObject.name == "GameObjectA") {
   score += 10;
   textMeshComponent = GameObject.Find ("Score").GetComponent<TextMesh> ();
   textMeshComponent.text = score.ToString ();

  }

Comment: That is an example of how the collision adds 10 to my integer score. How would I get started in making a foreach loop with that?

Comment: Turn the score  to a string. It's only the characters you care about when representing in the 3d font. So if score is 456, then you want a 4, a 5 and a 6

Comment: How do I get individual char out of a string like that?

Comment: Google it, this is not related to the question, or look at the now complete answer.

Comment: Oh nice thank you Minzkraut for the great explanation and you too Catwood you guys point the young programmers in the right direction and we learn to be like you !

Comment: One last question what does the offset to a variable mean?

Comment: when you instantiate a number... you have to add its with to a variable... so you don't instantiate the next one right on top. depending on your text align ment youd for example spawn a 4 and then 15 unity to the right the 5 etc.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the help. This is a resource that was lacking from the internet and I'm sure many many people will find in the future.